# Carrierwave+Sidekiq dynamic version issue, recreate in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, sidekiq, rails-activejob

When I create a new device then new version are added to my image uploader.
Then I run a job to recreate files for each MyModel record.
Sidekiq start job but it does not create files.
I use ActiveJob for declaring jobs.

This code:

```
MakingNewVersionImagesJob.perform_later("some_recently_added_device_name")
```

works fine in console after Sidekiq restart.
I think Sidekiq does not see MyModel changes.
Am I right? Is any solution here?

NOTE: it works fine when I do it directly in controller, not in background

```
class BaseImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Config/versions ...

  def self.add_version(name, width, height)
    version name do
      process resize_to_fit: [width, height]
    end
  end
end


class MyModelImageUploader < BaseImageUploader
  # blabla
end


class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  mount_uploader :image, MyModelImageUploader
end


class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :add_uploaders_versions

  def add_uploaders_versions
    version = self.name.downcase.to_sym
    MyModelImageUploader.add_version(version, self.width, self.height)
  end
end


class MakingNewVersionImagesJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :regular

  def perform(version)
    MyModel.find_each do |record|
      record.image.recreate_versions!(version.to_sym)
      record.save!
    end
  end
end


class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  #...
  def create
    @device = Device.new(device_params)
    if @device.save
      MakingNewVersionImagesJob.perform_later(@device.name.downcase)
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Sidekiq/Rails both load code to own memory area, that why Sidekiq knows nothing about class changes caused on Rails side.

In my solution I switched to DelayedJob. It loads an actual Rails context.

Also, I can duplicate definition of new version in MakingNewVersionImagesJob#perform and continue to use Sidekiq.